# LINQ query ToString returns strange string

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get a string from one field of the first record found by a LINQ query as follows:

```
Dim NameString As String = (From q In DContext.VoxContext.BurnPrograms
                            Where q.Id = acProgramId AndAlso q.Ac = True
                            Select q.ProgramName
                            Take 1).ToString
```

But when I follow this with:

```
If NameString = SomeOtherString
```

NameString is always:

> System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String]

I've tried several different permutations of the query, but can't seem to get it to work. It seems like the query isn't actually being made to run by the `ToString`. How should this be done correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Is it not important from which one found you will get data?

Comment: Well that's why I used `Take 1`, I thought that would give just the one item to get the data, No?

Comment: `Take` 1 will return 1 or no result but your where clause can return more than one result. And which one of them do you want to get using `Take`?

Comment: I'm not about the `TOP` but ordering.

Comment: Yup just realised that as I wrote it ;) => `From q In table Take 1 Where...`

Comment: Just to note that I've tried re-ordering the `Take 1` but this caused the query to return Nothing. So I'm currently using Nick's suggested `(From q in myTable Where q.Id = myId AndAlso q.Ac = True Select q.Name).FirstOrDefault` and so far it's working as intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with VB but this should do it

```
(From q In DContext.VoxContext.BurnPrograms
                            Where q.Id = acProgramId AndAlso q.Ac = True
                            Select q.ProgramName
                            Take 1).FirstOrDefault().ToString()
```

or a more elegant solution is to incorporate the lambda expression inside the FirstOrDefault:

```
var someString = DContext.VoxContext.BurnPrograms.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Id = acProgramId And x.Ac).ProgramName;
```

Comment: Assuming that q.ProgramName is already of type string, you don't event need to call .ToString(), as FirstOrDefault() will return a string.

Comment: What's the point of using `FirstOrDefault` if you call `ToString()` or access `ProgramName` on the returned object without checking for `null`? If you know there will be *at least one* element, use `First` to make that clear. If you know there will be *exactly one* element, use `Single`.

Comment: Thanks for the added info @DominicKexel, in this case though I dont actually know how many could be returned. It *should* be exactly one, but *could* be zero if the Id is not found or Ac is not True, or possibly more if there are somehow multiple Id's with the same value.

Comment: Perhaps best to check if what is returned from FirstOrDefault isn't Null before accessing .ProgramName in that case, that should cover all the cases